# Filament Laravel Project

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, localhost, laravel-filament

I'm encountering an issue with my Laravel Filament project. When I run it using php artisan serve, everything functions correctly. However, upon attempting to access the project via localhost, I encounter the following error message: "The POST method is not supported for the route admin/login. Supported methods: GET, HEAD."

I've attempted various installation methods, but unfortunately, the issue persists. Could someone provide guidance on resolving this? Your assistance is greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Inspect the network console if the Livewire Assets is returning 404. If yes, try publish the livewire assets: `php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets`

Comment: Thank you for your answer bro, after I run the code php artisan vendor:publish --force --tag=livewire:assets, the next error is this , Not Found, The requested URL was not found on this server. Apache/2.4.58 (Win64) OpenSSL/3.1.3 PHP/8.2.12 Server at localhost Port 80.